# Customized facebook login page

Tags: facebook, authentication, customization

Can we customize facebook login/authentication page?

I want to use my own customized pop up for receiving 'Email' and 'Password' input from user so that it is consistent with the GUI of my application. Is there a facebook API to which I can pass the Email/Password details received from user?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#permissions  you cannot "create" new permissions. This has to go through Facebook so they know what permissions have been granted. This ensures that you're not just granting permissions on behalf of a user without them having actively granted them. This therefore stands to reason that you cannot style their page.

Alternatively, you could just make sure users register via an account on your site (You want a password so I assume you don't mean their facebook password) and then ask them to connect their facebook account to it. You would need to ask for their email in your form, get them to login, then connect via facebook and associate their facebook id with their account on your site.